# o/p suppose i have 2 columns name A B and it contains data if user select A then display data for both; and if B then only show data +nt in column B

Tags: excel-formula

| USA | India |
| --- | --- |
| New York | Pune |
| Los Angeles | Delhi |

if USA then shows both Option
USA--> New York, or all data
India --> Pune mumbai delhi etc
If India then select data present in India only.
there must not third option shows to user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your title is almost longer and more detailed than the question itself. What's this really about? Dependent dropdown? Give more details, show what you mean by examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to create a pull down list. Here's one solution

1. Create a list of the desired USA cities in one column (on another sheet if you want to hide it)
2. Do the same thing for cities in India
3. Select "Data" from the excel ribbon
4. Then select the data validation option
5. Next position the cursor over the cell you want the pulldown to appear.
6. Next select the list of cities in USA.
7. You will have a pull down of USA cities
8. Repeat this process for the list of cities in India.